# CSS- Text Slider Testimonial?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a Text slider for a testimonial section on my website.
I found 2 codepens but i'd like someone to help me out to combine them.

I want this slider:
[codepen 1](https://overloath.000webhostapp.com/1.html)

But it should change automatically like this one:
        [codepen 2](https://overloath.000webhostapp.com/2.html)

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it so. Just added JS which finds current slide, amount of them and changes the checked radio.

https://codepen.io/CrUsH20/pen/eEwBga

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide0" checked="checked" class="slider__nav"/>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide1" class="slider__nav"/>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide2" class="slider__nav"/>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide3" class="slider__nav"/>
  <div class="slider__inner">
    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-codepen"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">codepen</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">newspaper-o</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-television"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">television</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-diamond"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">diamond</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500);
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.slider {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.slider__nav {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2rem 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  outline: 6px solid #ccc;
  outline-offset: -6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.slider__nav:checked {
  -webkit-animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
          animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .slider__inner {
  left: 0%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .slider__inner {
  left: -100%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .slider__inner {
  left: -200%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ .slider__inner {
  left: -300%;
}
.slider__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
  transition: left 0.4s;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.slider__contents {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.slider__image {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
      color: #2196F3;
}
.slider__caption {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 2rem 0 1rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.slider__txt {
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  max-width: 300px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes check {
  50% {
    outline-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
  }
  100% {
    outline-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes check {
  50% {
    outline-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
  }
  100% {
    outline-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
console.clear();

var slides = $('input[name="slider"]'),
    amount = slides.length,
    number = null,
    currentSlide = null;
console.log(slides);

$(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    currentSlide = $('input[name="slider"]:checked');
    number = parseInt($(currentSlide).attr('title').slice(5,6));

    console.log('---Current slide');
    console.log(number); //current slide number

    console.log('---Slides array');
    console.log(slides);

    if (number < (amount - 1)) {
      $(slides[number+1]).prop('checked', true);
      console.log('%c---Slide changed to next', 'color: green;');
    } else {
      $(slides[0]).prop('checked', true);
      console.log('%c---Slide changed to 0', 'color: red;');
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

jQuery is used.

Comment: Works perfectly! I just want to know how to change the time between the slides

Comment: There is a `setInterval` with 2000 delay. This delay is time between slides.

Comment: @DV There is also JS library bxslider.com where you can get ready-made slider with lots of settings.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the checkboxes/radio buttons and still get the same effect?

Comment: @DV yes. Just set `input[type="radio"] {display: none;}`